# SQL join query with group by clause?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.salary, e.department_id, d.department_name
FROM employees e, departments d
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department_name;
```

## output:

```
SQL> SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.salary, e.department_id, d.department_name
  2  FROM employees e, departments d
  3  WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
  4  GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department_name;
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.salary, e.department_id, d.department_name
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

What's wrong with this code?
I want all the cloumn (**e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.salary, e.department_id, d.department_name**) and also want to **group by** with (**d.department_id, d.department_name**) is it possible or not?

Comment: What output are you getting ? What is your expected output ?

Comment: SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.salary, e.department_id, d.department_name
           *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: I want all the column as output and group by only (d.department_id, d.department_name) ... Is it possible or not?

Comment: No it is not possible .

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

Refer this code. it will be work.

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, e.salary, e.did, d.dname
FROM [dbo].[Table_1] e join [dbo].[Table_2] d
on e.did = d.did
GROUP BY e.id, e.name, e.salary, e.did, d.dname;
```

or

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, e.salary, e.did, d.dname
FROM [dbo].[Table_1] e , [dbo].[Table_2] d
WHERE  e.did = d.did
GROUP BY e.id, e.name, e.salary, e.did, d.dname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only select columns which are in your group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule for GROUP BY clause, you should include all the columns that are not part of Aggregation. In this case you need to include all the columns in the GROUP BY Clause

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of below :

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.salary, e.department_id, d.department_name
FROM employees e, departments d
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.salary, e.department_id, d.department_name;
```

or

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, SUM(e.salary), e.department_id, d.department_name
FROM employees e, departments d
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id, d.department_name;
```